# How to strip a tag and all of its inner html using the tag's id?

Tags: php, html, replace, tags, domparser

I have the following html:

```
<html>
 <body>
 bla bla bla bla
  <div id="myDiv"> 
         more text
      <div id="anotherDiv">
           And even more text
      </div>
  </div>

  bla bla bla
 </body>
</html>
```

I want to remove everything starting from `<div id="anotherDiv">` until its closing `<div>`. How do I do that?

Comment: There seems to be an edit war on this page.  Please clarify this Unclear question so that researchers can benefit.

Comment: There is a big difference between removing a single, specific element versus removing all tags with a specific tagname.

Comment: Every regex solution to this question is incorrect, for any interpretation of this question, and will fail in surprising ways on many different inputs. You need a DOM parser, as the accepted answer uses. Whether you thought the question wanted to strip a `<div>`, or strip an element by its ID, neither option can be accomplished correctly with a regular expression.

Comment: Consider stripping `<div>` (by tag or by ID) from `<div data-attr="</div>"></div>` with a  regex. Or `<div><script>foo("</div>")</script></div>`, or any other number of simple cases that will break a regex-based solution.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

With [native DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($htmlString);
$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xPath->query('//*[@id="anotherDiv"]');
if($nodes->item(0)) {
    $nodes->item(0)->parentNode->removeChild($nodes->item(0));
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: what i have to modify if i want to remove all div tag in a dom?

Comment: @Sisir see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177376/delete-all-elements-of-a-certain-type-from-an-xml-doc-using-php/4177407#4177407

Comment: yes this works a treat.  Ive always wante dto be able to remove an html tag form a string of html much like a jquery $(selector#id).remove().   This is just brilliant!

Comment: @SubstanceD if you want selectors check out [phpQuery, Zend_Dom or QueryPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php/3577662#3577662). Personally, I prefer [XPath](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html).

Answer (score 14):

You can use `preg_replace()` like:

```
$string = preg_replace('/<div id="someid"[^>]+\>/i', "", $string);
```

Comment: this will remove all `div`s and not only the specified one.

Comment: You don't specify anywhere that it must remove the div with the ID=myDiv?

Comment: @HaimEvgi Is there any way to remove the content inner? for example using p tags it'll be removed, but the content of the p tags remains.

Comment: this rocks, but is there anyway to remove the closing </div> tag?

Comment: Here is a simple way to strip specific tags(both open & closing): https://gist.github.com/tedicela/0b06265eefb8df41cb8256bb3f442916

Comment: This answer DEFINITELY doesn't do what the OP requires.  16 UVs means that lots of researchers have been misinformed and don't understand the question and/or what this answer does.  This answer does far more harm than good.  The overarching message should be that developers should use a dom parser to manipulate valid html.

Comment: Question says: _I want to remove everything starting from <div id="anotherDiv"> until its closing <div>. How do I do that?_ **This answer is incorrect.**

Comment: This is incorrect and fails for `<div id="someid" data-foo=">">`. You cannot use a regex for this.

Answer (score 5):

Using the native [XML Manipulation Library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php)

Assuming that your html content is stored in the variable $html:

```
$html='<html>
 <body>
 bla bla bla bla
  <div id="myDiv"> 
         more text
      <div id="anotherDiv">
           And even more text
      </div>
  </div>

  bla bla bla
 </body>
</html>';
```

To delete the tag by ID use the following code:

```
    $dom=new DOMDocument;

    $dom->validateOnParse = false;

    $dom->loadHTML( $html );

    // get the tag

    $div = $dom->getElementById('anotherDiv');

   // delete the tag

    if( $div && $div->nodeType==XML_ELEMENT_NODE ){

        $div->parentNode->removeChild( $div );
    }

    echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Note that certain versions of `libxml` require a `doctype` to be present in order to use the `getElementById` method.

In that case you can prepend $html with `<!doctype>`

```
$html = '<!doctype>' . $html;
```

Alternatively, as suggested by Gordon's answer, you can use `DOMXPath` to find the element using the xpath:

```
$dom=new DOMDocument;

$dom->validateOnParse = false;

$dom->loadHTML( $html );

$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );

$col = $xp->query( '//div[ @id="anotherDiv" ]' );

if( !empty( $col ) ){

    foreach( $col as $node ){

        $node->parentNode->removeChild( $node );

    }

}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

The first method works regardless the tag. If you want to use the second method with the same id but a different tag, let say `form`, simply replace `//div` in `//div[ @id="anotherDiv" ]` by '`//form`'

Answer (score 0):

strip_tags() function is what you are looking for.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: trip_tags() doesn’t work the way he want it to. strip_tags()  allows for certain exclusions, but why would you use that when you only want to exclude one tag and include all other tags

Comment: From his question, I couldn't really tell what tags he was trying to remove.  It seemed as if he wanted to remove everything.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Ahhh, using chrome.  His inline markup didn't show up.  I just checked it in firefox and I see his inline markup.  You are correct :)  Any reason why it didn't show up in chrome?

Comment: strip_tags() worked best for me. Thanks. The reason it worked best for me is because i had tags that had no spaces. It was the easiest by far. thanks.

Comment: Question says: _I want to remove everything starting from <div id="anotherDiv"> until its closing <div>. How do I do that?_ **This answer is incorrect.**

Answer (score -1):

I wrote these to strip specific tags and attributes. Since they're regex they're not 100% guaranteed to work in all cases, but it was a fair tradeoff for me:

```
// Strips only the given tags in the given HTML string.
function strip_tags_blacklist($html, $tags) {
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $regex = '#<\s*' . $tag . '[^>]*>.*?<\s*/\s*'. $tag . '>#msi';
        $html = preg_replace($regex, '', $html);
    }
    return $html;
}

// Strips the given attributes found in the given HTML string.
function strip_attributes($html, $atts) {
    foreach ($atts as $att) {
        $regex = '#\b' . $att . '\b(\s*=\s*[\'"][^\'"]*[\'"])?(?=[^<]*>)#msi';
        $html = preg_replace($regex, '', $html);
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Regex is DOM-ignorant and is prone to failure.  Using a legitimate DOM parsing technique will be more robust, reliable, and scalable. Iterated `preg_` calls is going to be inefficient.  The `m` pattern modifier is of no use.

Comment: This answer does not target the tag using the `id` as stated in the question.  This answer is incorrect because it with remove elements that should not be removed.

Answer (score -1):

how about this?

```
// Strips only the given tags in the given HTML string.
function strip_tags_blacklist($html, $tags) {
    $html = preg_replace('/<'. $tags .'\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/'. $tags .'>/is', "", $html);
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Regex is DOM-ignorant and is prone to failure.  Using a legitimate DOM parsing technique will be more robust, reliable, and scalable.  There is no reason to declare `$html` (a single-use variable); just `return preg_replace(...);`  This snippet will fail when a tag attribute value contains `>`. There is no need to use a capture group.

Comment: This answer does not target the tag using the `id` as stated in the question.  This answer is incorrect because it with remove elements that should not be removed.

Comment: This is incorrect and fails for many kinds of input, for example `strip_tags_blacklist('<script>let x = "<div>"></script><div>foo</div>', 'div')` => `<script>let x = "`. You cannot use regular expressions to strip or otherwise interact with HTML.

Answer (score -1):

Following RafaSashi's answer using `preg_replace()`, here's a version that works for a single tag or an array of tags:

```
/**
 * @param $str string
 * @param $tags string | array
 * @return string
 */

function strip_specific_tags ($str, $tags) {
  if (!is_array($tags)) { $tags = array($tags); }

  foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $_str = preg_replace('/<\/' . $tag . '>/i', '', $str);
    if ($_str != $str) {
      $str = preg_replace('/<' . $tag . '[^>]*>/i', '', $_str);
    }
  }
  return $str;
}
```

Comment: Question says: _I want to remove everything starting from <div id="anotherDiv"> until its closing <div>. How do I do that?_ **This answer is incorrect.**

Comment: This answer does not target the tag using the `id` as stated in the question.  This answer is incorrect because it with remove elements that should not be removed.