# How do I search for and replace a specific area of content in a HTML document using preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a HTML document with the a table which I want to replace, however I don't know what the content of the table will be so I need to search for the opening and closing table tags and then replace the content between them. I'm a bit of a n00b with regular expressions so I'm having trouble working out how to do this... any ideas?

Update: The HTML in question is available to me as a string and I'm not able to insert any extra data or change the HTML in any way... I need to be able to search for a opening and closing pattern at the start and end of the table in the HTML and then replace the contents in-between. :)

Comment: If you are too lazy to use the search function, I am too lazy to find the duplicate, but be assured it is in there: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A208809+replace+DOM

Comment: I'm not too lazy to use the search function, I just didn't find any previous questions and answers that gave me what I needed. :)

Comment: second link in the linked search results and Wrikken's answer should give you all you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Strip a specific tag from HTML string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308530/php-strip-a-specific-tag-from-html-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do NOT use regular expressons for this, look into parsers. For instance, load the HTML in a `DOMDocument` instance, search the table with either `DOMXPath` or `getElementsByTagName`, and use the `replaceNode` or other manipulation functions. Doing it with regexes is usually very unreliable.

Comment: I need to do this server side unfortunately but thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: Parsing XML server side is what the XML functions of PHP are for.

Comment: Wow, ok... I didn't even realise this was possible.. sorry, I just assumed you had misunderstood my question. Will definitely have a look for a primer on native DOM manipulation with PHP. Thanks. :)

Comment: ok, well I found a solution while in part uses the techniques you;ve suggested so thanks very much for that.

As I have a large HTML string as a PHP variable it was easier to find the table in question using the DOM method you suggested, replace it with a placeholder node and then str_replace the placeholder node with the string contents. :)

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Is the HTML document your own, or `file_get_contents()`ed from a another site? If the first, just change the HTML to

```
<html>
 ...
<table>
    <?php echo $tableString ?>
</table>
 ...
</html>
```

and give it a `.php` or `.inc` extension. Then, in your main file:

```
<?php
    $tableString = calcTableContents();
    require('includedHTML.inc');
?>
```

No point parsing HTML if you don't have to.

Comment: That is an interesting interpretation of the question.

Comment: Often the asker of the question knows what they want, but follow the wrong route to get it.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't effect the HTML in any way before it's available to me as a string in PHP. In retrospect I now realise my original question lacked context so apologies for that. :)