# Convert DOMElement to string and then strip unwanted tags

Tags: php, xml, string, dom

Now, thanks to community, one problem was fixed ( [Delete all elements of a certain type from an XML doc using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177376/delete-all-elements-of-a-certain-type-from-an-xml-doc-using-php) ). Now I luckily hit other :)

So, I have XML file:

```
<piletilve_info>
   <shows>
      <show>
        <description>
          <lat>
        <![CDATA[ 
LA CENERENTOLA  <BR><BR>

("Cinderella")<BR><BR>

Opera buffo by Gioachino Rossini<BR><BR>


Music Director and Conductor: Arvo Volmer<BR>
Stage Director and Set Designer: Michiel Dijkema (Amsterdam)<BR>
Costumes: Claudia Damm (Berlin)<BR><BR>



Premiere on November 10, 2006<BR>
Approx running time: 3 h 20 min<BR>
Sung in Italian with subtitles in Estonian and English<BR><BR>

Who hasn’t heard the fairy-tale of Cinderella who crouched in the ashes, danced to the tune of her step-sisters but finally found the man of her dreams and a happy life. Why should this fairy-tale be told today?<BR>
An exciting and unexpected solution of the story of Cinderella with striking scenery and fantastic-modern costumes is presented by the Dutch stage director Michiel Dijkema and the German designer Claudia Damm.<BR>
In this story, an unhappy soul dreams of a prince on a white horse and of a better life, and women following the last trends chase the prince, and a man who considers himself very wise, is only interested in himself.<BR>
"Cinderella" is not just a fairy-tale, it includes reality as well as dreams, a lot of fantasies, comedy and grotesque. And all of this is expressed by the brilliant and virtuous music of Rossini!<BR>

  ]]> 
          </lat>
        </description>
      </show>
   </shows>
   <other node>
      ...
   </other node>
</piletilve_info>
```

I navigate to my needed node using this code:

```
$books = $xpath->query('shows/show/description');
        foreach($books as $description)
        {
            $description->removeChild($eng_lang);
            $lat_lang = $description->getElementsByTagName('lat')->item(0);
            }
```

I want to output modified `$lat_lang` elements , which is `<[[CDATA ]]>` parent, content using this mixed function:

```
$lat_lang->nodeValue = mb_convert_encoding(print_r(strip_tags_only($lat_lang->item(0)->nodeValue, TRUE),'<html><head><body>'), 'UTF-8' ,$encoding);
```

, but I fail and when I execute script on apache server, I get this error:

> The XML page cannot be displayed 
>   Cannot view XML input using XSL style
>   sheet. Please correct the error and
>   then click the Refresh button, or try
>   again later.
>
> ---
>
> Only one top level element is allowed
>   in an XML document. Error processing
>   resource
>   'http://www.bilesuserviss.lv/lv_filtrs_...
>
> **Catchable fatal error**:  Object
>   of class DOMElement could not be
>   converted to string in /var/www/...

Could you help me finding solution?

Maybe the fact I do develop on delphi makes me this whole PHP<->XML coding more difficult that for normal people would .. :(

Comment: please provide a snippet of the XML please

Comment: Strip_tags_only(); : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php . First comment for strp_tags(); function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was spelling problem. 
Function name was strip_only_tags(), but I called it with strip_tags_only();

I am working on delphi and php<>xml project whole day .. Kinda feel tired already :(
Sorry all.

Also thansk to Gordon for commept. Kinda woke me up :D