# Using PHP: Need to delete all matching XML nodes

Tags: php, xml

Everyone,

Apologies for the simplicity. I'm using PHP and XML for a quick one-off, when I'm much more comfortable in C# and SQL Server.

I have an XML file that looks something like this:

```
<items>
    <item>
         <name>Item A</name>
         <sort>2</sort>
    </item>

    <item>
         <name>Item B</name>
         <sort>3</sort>
    </item>

    <item>
         <name>Item C</name>
         <sort>1</sort>
    </item>
</items>
```

I need to delete all of the sort nodes, to this:

```
<items>
    <item>
         <name>Item A</name>
    </item>

    <item>
         <name>Item B</name>
    </item>

    <item>
         <name>Item C</name>
    </item>
</items>
```

Should be very simple, right?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177376/delete-all-elements-of-a-certain-type-from-an-xml-doc-using-php

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I must've read every post *besides* that one. Sorry for the duplication -- though hopefully someone in need will see this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
foreach($xml->item as $item) {
        unset($item->sort);
}
echo $xml->asXml();
```

Tested this.. simplexml is easier in my opinion. You would then write "$xml->asXML()" to your file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Gordon's link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177376/delete-all-elements-of-a-certain-type-from-an-xml-doc-using-php as a duplicate worked exactly as needed in my instance.

Comment: no problem, I also updated my answer with simplexml. It actually works. ;)

Comment: I like this much better. Thanks again!