# php remove first <p> and last </p> tags from string

Tags: php

How to remove first

and last

tags from string??
example string:

```
$string = "<p>text text<br>text<p>text</p></p>";
```

Comment: dup : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308530/php-strip-a-specific-tag-from-html-string

Comment: trim() **before** adding these silly `<p>`'s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = "<p>text text<br>text<p>text</p></p>";

$pattern = "=^<p>(.*)</p>$=i";

echo preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches). "<br />" ;
var_dump($matches);
```

gives me:

```
1<br />
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(35) "<p>text text<br>text<p>text</p></p>"
  [1]=>
  string(28) "text text<br>text<p>text</p>"
}
```

Comment: Note, I made a booboo regarding the pattern line. the i was between the $ and = ($i=) but should had been like $=i. Please also edit in your own code. It can lead to unexpected errors if you happen to have used a var i in the same scope.

Comment: preg_replace is also possible, but preg_match gives more control over the returnd value. If the user input is invalid (<p>tekst1<p>tekst2</p>tekst3</p>tekst4) using preg_match would return false and an empty array where preg_replace would return the 'subject' string. Thus you can enclose it in an if-statement to validate the input as well. I always prefer to enclose preg_replace with a preg_match. Feels safer.

Answer (score 23):

Try

```
$string = preg_replace('/<p[^>]*>(.*)<\/p[^>]*>/i', '$1', $string);
```

Comment: I added `/is` as my string had multiples lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!!!

```
$s="  <p>  Hello world  </p>  ";
$s = trim(preg_replace('#^<p>|</p>$#i', '', trim($s)));
echo '<p><textarea >'.$s.'</textarea>';
```