# Remove text box from twitter widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, twitter

I have created twitter widget from my twitter account to put it in my web page.

It works fine, but i want to customize it.

I just want to remove text box from the bottom.

And want to resize it. I want to set its height to 120px only. But by default it takes 200px. So is there anyway to do that?

**What i have tried :**

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" width="500" height="120"  href="https://twitter.com/name"  data-widget-id="4745229851234567856">Tweets by @name</a>
```

So how can i do that ?

Here i have attach screen shots.

**Currently Getting :**

[image]

**Expecting :**

[image]

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: sounds similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308530/php-strip-a-specific-tag-from-html-string

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use TweetDeck.

https://blog.twitter.com/2013/custom-timelines-in-tweetdeck

EDIT:

There's a discussion about your issue here: http://dev.twitter.com/discussions/11532

Comment: i have tried this, but i can't get follow button in the top bar.And this will show only particular timeline.