# PHP: Strip specific tags but leave content

Tags: php, regex, dom

I want to remove specific `<font>` tags from my html only if a class attribute doesn't exist.  I've already tried using the below regex:

```
/<font(.*?)>(.*?)<\/font>/
```

along with `preg_replace()`, but in my case it won't work because the tags are sometimes nested.

For example:

```
<font>
  <a><font class="junk"></font></a>
<font>
```

If I run the regex once it becomes:

```
  <a><font class="junk"></a>
<font>
```

Because the second `<font>` tag has a class attribute on it, that tag won't be removed and the HTML is potentially screwed up.

My desired outcome would be the below:

```
<a><font class="junk"></font></a>
```

I want `<font>` tags removed only if they do not have a `class` attribute.

Hence, my need for something else besides regex.  I'm aware that you shouldn't parse HTML with regex (I know what Bobince wrote).  I'm also aware that you can load the DOMDocument.  Something like the below, which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308530/php-strip-a-specific-tag-from-html-string):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
```

However, the solutions that I have seen have also stripped the content out between the tags.  I only want the tags themselves removed, but the content to remain.  Is that possible using the native DOM?

Comment: And here's why you don't use regexes on html... html in, garbage out. You can use DOM for this quite easily, but you have to realize that you're now dealing with a TREE, not a flat string. if you want to remove a node in the tree but keep its branches, you'll have to do some pruning/grafting.

Comment: @MarcB Yes.  I am now beginning to see the value of the native DOM.  Could you lead me in the right direction as to how I could remove the tags but keep the content in using the DOM?

Comment: @Keven Can you put your desired output?

Comment: @fede See update.  Does that clarify?

Comment: @Keven I'll try to figure out a solution. Doesn't it work the built-in php function http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php ?

Comment: basically, find the node(s) you want to remove, then use [removeChild()](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php) to prune that from the tree. then you'll need to grab the innerHTML of that removed node and slip that into the place the original node used to be.

Comment: @Fede If `strip_tags()` gave me a blacklist, then that would work.  But it only allows me to specify which elements are allowed.

Comment: @Keven yes, I know you have to put the allowed tags, I think that is very tedious. I posted an answer with an screenshot showing how you can do it with regex.

Comment: Can you check your question: `For example: ...` includes 3 opening `<font`. Did you mean `<font>
  <a><font class="junk"></font></a>
</font>` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
<font class.*?>.*?<\/font>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(<font>|<\/font>)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/zW9eN5/2)**

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... touche.  However, I can't help but think that somewhere... buried deep inside the HTML... there is a font tag that still won't be matched by this...

Comment: @Keven can you update the link I provided you with the content so I can see it?

Comment: I have no specific example.  However, I did need to change your regex to `<font class.*?>.*?<\/font>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(<font.*?>|<\/font>)` so that it would match font tags which had other attributes besides class attributes.  I know I didn't mention that as a requirement, so don't worry about including it.

Comment: Also, does PHP support `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`?

Comment: @Keven yes it does. In the link I provided you it says Pcre(php) :)

Comment: @Keven did my answer answered to your question?

Comment: Yes and no.  It did give me a regex which could serve as a solution, however, it doesn't address an alternative to regex.  You should definitely keep it up so others can use it if they would like.  I might still end up using it, but I would like to exhaust all other possibilities first.

Comment: @Keven ok sure, sorry I misunderstood the question, I thought you wanted a regex as a solution. Btw, thanks for the +1.

Comment: @Fede +1 for the idea, but it does not deal correctly with nesting, [see example](http://regex101.com/r/zW9eN5/3).

Answer (score 0):

Grab each line that contains `<font`...

Note the indexAt of `<font` and remove everything from that until the firstIndexOf `>` that is after that.

(for example:

```
while(strpos($html,'<font')>-1 ) {
    $removeFrom = strpos($html,"<font");
    $removeTo = strpos($html,">",$removeFrom+1);
    $html = substr($html,0,$removeFrom).substr($html,$removeTo);
}
```

Then simply remove all `</font>` from everywhere with a `str_replace('<\font>','',$html)`

Not as slick as a single regex, but should work and is only a few lines of real code.

Comment: I like this response, and will try it, but first I want to see if it can be done using `DOMDocument`.

Comment: Always good to try new things.   The above works, though, it might not be the most efficient.  Luckily, parsing HTML isn't particularly resource-intensive in the first place.