# How remove multiple substring from two tags

Tags: php, string

Gived a string so formed:

```
hello Rose <tag> Micheal </tag> and <tag> July </tag> John.
```

I want remove all between `<tag>` and `</tag>` and to have in output:

```
hello Rose and John.
```

how i can it?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I have found here function called:  delete_all_between but it work only with first occurrency but not with all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Strip a specific tag from HTML string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308530/php-strip-a-specific-tag-from-html-string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you can use:

```
$new_html = preg_replace('%<tag>.*?</tag> ?%si', '', $old_html);
```

Comment: work! But there is a bug. When string end with <tag>something</tag> it not work; how fix it?

Comment: Just make the space `optional`, with `?`, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), you could always use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to do this.

```
$content = 'hello Rose <tag> Micheal </tag> and <tag> July </tag> John.';

$content = preg_replace('/<tag>[^<]+<\/tag>/i', '', $content);

print $content; // returns: hello Rose and John.
```