# Strip just <p> tags in PHP

Tags: php, strip

I have a set of `<p></p>` tags wrapping a set of data, that data includes other tags such as `<script></script>` however that content could contain any number of different tags.

I just need to remove any paragraph tags from the content

Example below

```
$text = "<p><script>example text inside script.<script></p>";
```

I see the strip_tags function but I believe that will remove all the tags.

How would I go about just removing the paragraph?

Thanks.

Comment: this might help you, as strip_tags won't do what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31380542/2119863

Comment: Can't you simply use str_replace to remove the start and end tags of paragraphs? If you don't intend to expand on removing more tags this seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: Check my answer with `strip_tags`, you can decide which tags are allowed, maybe it would be a better solution for you.

Comment: *"I see the strip_tags function but I believe that will remove all the tags."* - You can do omissions. As per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php *"**allowable_tags** 

    You can use the optional second parameter to specify tags which should not be stripped."*

Comment: @KarolGasienica I'm not the downvoter and you are correct that [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) can specify which tags should not be stripped. As per my above comment.

Answer (score 10):

Try,

```
$text = "<p><script>example text inside script.<script></p>";

$formatted_text = str_replace(['<p>', '</p>'], '', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can allow tag with strip_tags()
like this example:

```
$text = "<p><script>example text inside script.<script></p>";
echo strip_tags($text, '<script>');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
<?php
$text = "<p><script>example text inside script.<script></p>";
$replace = array('<p>','</p>');
echo str_replace($replace,'',$text);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/43150c7af4e7e5f572827d91abca5756213ab7ba

Version 2 (works for classes)

```
echo preg_replace('%<p(.*?)>|</p>%s','',$text);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6c5414773efc1317578b5f0581b68e5acabb9a2b

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any other way other than a replacement? Don't know why this answer is downvoted.

Answer (score -4):

You can use str_replace(),
add this line -

```
$text = str_replace('<p>','',$text);
$text = str_replace('</p>','',$text);
```

It will remove both

```
<p> and </p>
```

Comment: Strange, but answer by @D34dman has positive rating, but this anwer, which is the same I think, has negative rating.