# Remove <p> tag from HTML content

Tags: php, preg-replace, strip-tags

I trying to get a clean paragraph to be displayed on the website but, because of the `<p></p>` in the middle of the content I am not getting the expected output. I have tried the following but none of them worked and I am still getting `<p></p>` around my content.

```
$story = "<p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p><p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>";


 1. $story = strip_tags($story, '<p>');
 2. $story=str_ireplace('<p>','',$story);
 3. $story=str_ireplace('</p>','',$story);
 4. $story = preg_replace('/<p\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/p>/i', '', $story);
```

Have I missed anything in my code? My expected output would be

> Answer: Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

Comment: Does the $story contain only `<p>` html tag and no other HTML tag?

Comment: If you pass `<p>` as the second argument to `strip_tags()`, you're telling the function to _allow_ that tag, not to remove it. If you want to strip all tags, just omit the second argument. If you want to keep other html tags, that's the ones you should pass as a second argument.  [Here's the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @vivek_23 I do have `<img>` tag in content but for now, I just want to remove `<p>` tag from the content($story).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Strip a specific tag from HTML string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308530/php-strip-a-specific-tag-from-html-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way with `str_replace()`

```
<?php
$story = "<p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p><p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>";
$result = str_replace(['<p>','</p>'],['',''],$story);
echo $result;
?>
```

**DEMO** : https://3v4l.org/nllPP

**OR** with [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to remove all tags, by the way with this method you can specify **allowable_tags**

```
$result = strip_tags($story);
```

Comment: I saw the demo which is working perfectly fine but I am not getting the same output in my code. I am fetching Unicode character in the variable `$story`, is that causing me a problem?

Comment: Each answer given by you is working perfectly here: https://3v4l.org/nllPP but not in my code.

Comment: have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176904/php-how-to-remove-all-non-printable-characters-in-a-string

Comment: I looked over there but no use. And, yes I tried with Unicode character outside the loop which worked but I am displaying `$story` in foreach loop and that is not working.

Answer (score 2):

PHP has built-in functions to remove the HTML tags from a string. It is better to use `strip_tags()` rather than `str_replace()`, Here is an example

```
     $story = "<p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p><p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>";
;
        $a = strip_tags($story);
        $b = strip_tags($story, "<strong><em>"); // can also pass the tags that you don't want to remove
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str_ireplace()` function .

```
$story = "<p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p><p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>";

echo $text=str_ireplace('<p>','',$story);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/W0Qeb

Answer (score 1):

```
$story = "<p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 
    1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a 
    type specimen book.</p><p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text 
    ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled 
    it to make a type specimen book.</p>";

$story = strip_tags($story) ;
echo $story;
```

there is a built in function that removes all html tags in php. strip_tags()